# Discord.py Bot - Mutual Friends

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a 1v1-style bot. For this Discord Bot, I need to know if two users are friends in Discord. I looked through the Docs and saw that there's a command to find mutual friends of someone. So then, I thought I could send a friend request to both users (as a bot), and then I could find mutual friends of each other to determine if the two users are friends. However, I couldn't send a friend request or verify mutual friends through the code (403 Forbidden: Endpoint not accessible by a bot user). Do I have to create my own friending system, or is there any way that I can (legally) figure out of two users are Discord friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can know if User1 is friend with User2, this is a breach of user privacy. Discord would not allow you to do so.